# Javascript framework 'blocked' in Google+ Hangout app (insecure content)

Tags: javascript, https, google-plus, google-hangouts

I'm trying to load a 3rd party library (specifically YUI2, to handle drag-and-drop) in a G+ Hangout app that I'm developing.

It's just included at the top of the HTML file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/combo?2.9.0/build/yahoo-dom-event/yahoo-dom-event.js"></script>
```

When run, Hangout refuses to load it, citing:

```
[blocked] The page at https://[app url] ran insecure content from http://[YUI2 url]
```

I'm assuming it's because Google's serving the app and the hangout through HTTPS, while the library's only going through HTTP, and it doesn't like mixing the two. The question is, how do I work around this? I don't want my users to have to change their settings to use my app, and I'd prefer to use Yahoo's host of the library rather than mirror it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. You need to embedd this script over HTTPS.

Yahoo does not offer [SSL support on their CDN](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/tutorials/faq/#does-yahoos-cdn-support-ssl). Read [why](http://wonko.com/post/javascript-ssl-cdn).

You may use the google CDN:

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/yui/2.9.0/build/yahoo-dom-event/yahoo-dom-event.js